# png image is not showing good in ie10 browser?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have used png image in my application.
Actual size is : 300px X 300px
I am using it's 20% as input image button. it showing good in Mozilla and Chrome browser.
But in IE it is distort.
Please see the attachments:

Please let me know if there any other attributes are there to fix this issue.

Issue in IE browser, Look at the circle buttons:

[image: Ie-Button issue]

Issue in Mozilla browser, Look at the circle buttons:

[image: Mozilla-Button issue]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Maybe resize the image in an image editor so you're not depending on the browser to do it for you?

Comment: @im1dermike: If you look at the circles of image, it not cleaned curve shape in IE but in Firefox curves are good

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: images are get resize according to device. so we can't resize the images for each device and we have to manage it in % or em etc...

Comment: Okay, you may want to add that to your question, along with an indication of what you've tried, so that we don't have to keep guessing :).

Answer (score 2):

Erm simple, disable border for image?

```
input[type=image] {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not working for us.